# Windows Server 2003 наглухо виснет

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-server

Windows Server 2003 SP2 виснет наглухо.(не реагирует на мышь, клавиатуру) только перезагрузка помогает.
В логах после перезагрузки вижу только сообщение что была жесткая перезагрузка.

Такое происходит не всегда, может две недели работать без зависание,а может и 4 дня. С чем связанно не пойму.

так же работает на сервере  WinCC v6.2

установлен sccm-client  без ввода в домен.

Подскажите,какими утилитами лучше сделать тест-системы? Так же программку для дополнительного логирование системы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните по классике. Вначале проверьте память - [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) или подобным. Убедитесь, что дело не в памяти.

Следующий этап - проверка температуры. Возможно он перегревается или что то подобное. Тут сложно что то предложить, ищите любую программу, которая умеет писать в лог.

И третий этап - а может это все таки прыжок напряжение в сети? но любой нормальный сервер должен иметь хоть минимальный UPS.

p.s. и совсем банально - может памяти мало, а какая то софтина все выедает?

Comment: memtest86, все советуют ее,начну с нее.